Every TVS is $T_{3.5}$ (Tychonoff) even if it is not $T_0$
I'm studying the first properties of Topological Vector space, and I'm confused about the separation properties. Is every TVS $T_{3.5}$ even if it is not $T_0$? This is confirmed by this wikipedia link, in which it's stated:

"A vector space is an abelian group with respect to the operation of addition, and in a topological vector space the inverse operation is always continuous (since it is the same as multiplication by ${\displaystyle -1}$). Hence, every topological vector space is an abelian topological group. Every TVS is completely regular"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Topological_structure
The confusion arises because in every other book it's stated the the $T_0$ property is necessary.

Short answer: T0 isn't necessary, but it's often added as a requirement. If you don't, you can obtain a T0 TVS by identifying the topologically indistinguishable points.

Also note that Tychonoff usually refers to $T_{3.5}$, which is equivalent to completely regular with $T_0$.

Its $T_{3.5}$ and not $T_3$. There is one convention in which $T_i$ properties should imply each other in the sense that if $i < j$ then $T_j$ implies $T_i$. Properties which have a name, like normal, regular, completely regular are usually assumed without any properties like $T_0$ and $T_1$, and so they usually don't form a chain like $T_i$ properties. For example there exists normal spaces which aren't regular or completely regular. This is just one convention of course and its one wikipedia uses

In the usual nomenclature $T_{3.5}$ should imply $T_0$, but completely regular and $T_{3.5}$ should mean something else. A space $X$ is completely regular if for a point $x\in X$ and closed set $F\subseteq X$ with $x\notin F$ there exists a continuous $f:X\to [0, 1]$ with $f(x) = 0, f[F]\subseteq {1}$. But this point $x$ doesn't have to be closed. However books often don't care about spaces with weaker separation properties (there is no need to). So in your book completely regular and $T_{3.5}$ might mean the same thing.

Every TVS is a topological group, and every topological group is completely regular. This can be seen by giving it a uniform structure of entourages of the form $\{(x,y):xy^{-1}\in U\}$ for each neighborhood $U$ of the identity.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Definition points out that one can additionally require Hausdorff (equivalently $T_0$ in this context) but it's not necessary. Any indiscrete space with multiple points is a non-$T_0$ TVS for example.

TVS are uniformizable and hence completely regular, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformizable_space
